# How can fix the segmentation fault on assembly?

Tags: c, assembly

I need help in assembly. I have this code on C, I need to traslate it on Assembly and the resultate must be returnet to C code like a reference. When I do it, I have a Segmentation fault. Someone can help me?

For more information: VettRis is the Array in which I put my result and it's builted making an addition with the element of another vector in input, called rigaDs

I've tried to make a print for the only register XMM0 and it's all ok. But when I do the mov, I have a segmentation Fault

```
    float rigaDs[]={13.0, 2.0,71.8, 9.0};
    float y[]={44.0, 1.4, 2.0, -4.0};
    int dim=4;
    float* vettRis; 
    centroGeo(rigaDs,dim, &vettRis);
    stampaVettore(vettRis,dim);
```

---

```
seciton .data

    rigaDs equ 8
    dim equ 12
    vettRis equ 16  

section .text

    push ebp
    mov ebp, esp
    pushad
    mov eax, [ebp+rigaDs]   
    mov edi, [ebp+dim] 
    mov ebx, [ebp+vettRis]
    xor esi, esi

forI:

    cmp esi, edi
    jge end
    movups xmm0, [eax+esi*4]
    movups [ebx+esi*4], xmm0
    inc esi
    jmp forI

end: 

    popad
    mov esp, ebp
    pop ebp 
    ret
```

the result should be 13.0, 2.0,71.8, 9.0

Comment: Where does `vettRis` point to?

Comment: in the case should be the copy of rigaDs (in assembly code), in C is a empty vector

Comment: There is a typo in the first line of your assembly. Although this is unrelated to the segfault, it _does_ make me wonder if this is really the version of your code that has been running into a segfault. It couldn't even pass the assembler.

Comment: The question "Where does vettRis point to" was supposed to be a hint ... it's not pointing anywhere because it's uninitialized. As such, you should not try to dereference it until you allocate some memory and assign to it.

Comment: @Jester Thank you for your answer. Now it's all clear! Thank you to mch and Ruud for your answer too!